# How to use d3+react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I have my project to use streaming chart to display my data , Well i use `React` to create my project web but i have no idea to use `d3code+react`.

http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

thank you.

Comment: Please include any relevant code you've written so far.

Answer (score 15):

We add modules using NPM and while we could include the entire D3 library and keep coding like we have, you’re better off installing the individual modules and understanding how importing those modules works. In your project directory run the following to install the d3-scale module:

```
npm i –SE d3-scale
```

This command (`npm i` is short for `npm install`) installs the latest version of `d3-scale` (which gives us access to all those wonderful scales we’ve been using in the last eight chapters) and the `–SE` tag saves the exact version to your `package.json` so that when you want to deploy this application elsewhere `d3-scale` is installed. Along with d3-scale, do the same thing with the following modules:

```
d3-shape
d3-svg-legend
d3-array
d3-geo
d3-selection
d3-transition
d3-brush
d3-axis
```

By installing modules individually like this, you reduces the amount of code you’ll deploy with your application, decreasing load time and improving maintainability.

**D3 rendering with React -**
The challenge of integrating D3 with React is that React and D3 both want to control the DOM. The entire `select/enter/exit/update` pattern with D3 is in direct conflict with React and its virtual DOM. If you’re coming to React from D3, giving up your grip on the DOM is one of those “cold, dead hands” moments. The way most people use D3 with React is to use React to build the structure of the application, and to render traditional HTML elements, and then when it comes to the data visualization section, they pass a DOM container (typically an ) over to D3 and use D3 to create and destroy and update elements. In a way, it’s similar to the way we used to use Java applets or Flash to run a black box in your page while the rest of your page is rendered separately. The benefit of this method of integrating React and D3 is that you can use all the same kind of code you see in all the core D3 examples. The main difficulty is that you need to create functions in various React lifecycle events to make sure your viz updates.

The listing below shows a simple bar chart component built using this method.

> Example - 1

**BarChart.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale’
import { max } from 'd3-array'
import { select } from 'd3-selection'

class BarChart extends Component {

   constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      this.createBarChart()
   }

   componentDidUpdate() {
      this.createBarChart()
   }

   createBarChart() {
      const node = this.node
      const dataMax = max(this.props.data)
      const yScale = scaleLinear()
         .domain([0, dataMax])
         .range([0, this.props.size[1]])

   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')

   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .exit()
      .remove()

   select(node)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.props.data)
      .style('fill', '#fe9922')
      .attr('x', (d,i) => i * 25)
      .attr('y', d => this.props.size[1] — yScale(d))
      .attr('height', d => yScale(d))
      .attr('width', 25)
   }

render() {
      return <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
      width={500} height={500}>
      </svg>
   }
}

export default BarChart
```

Making these changes and saving them won’t show any immediate effect because you’re not importing and rendering this component in `app.js`, which is the component initially rendered by your app. Change `app.js` to match the following listing.

**Referencing BarChart.js in App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import BarChart from './BarChart'

class App extends Component {
   render() {
   return (
      <div className='App'>
      <div className='App-header'>
      <h2> D3 Dashboard</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
      <BarChart data={[5,10,1,3]} size={[500,500]} />
      </div>
      </div>
   )
   }
}

export default App
```

**This is Your React + D3 example, with a simple bar chart rendered.**

**There is other method also of rendering data visualization using D3 and React.**

**React for element creation, D3 as the visualization kernel -**
Rather than using ref to get the actual DOM node and passing that DOM node off to D3, you can use D3 to generate all the necessary drawing instructions and use React to create the actual DOM elements. There are challenges with this approach in creating animated transitions and draggable elements but otherwise it’s preferable because it will create code that will be more maintainable.

> Example - 2

**WorldMap.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import worlddata from './world'
import { geoMercator, geoPath } from 'd3-geo'

class WorldMap extends Component {
   render() {
      const projection = geoMercator()
      const pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection)
      const countries = worlddata.features
         .map((d,i) => <path
         key={'path' + i}
         d={pathGenerator(d)}
         className='countries'
         />)

   return <svg width={500} height={500}>
   {countries}
   </svg>
   }
}

export default WorldMap
```

**This is a basic map rendered via React and JSX with D3 providing the drawing instructions.**

> Example - 3

**StreamGraph.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { stack, area, curveBasis, stackOrderInsideOut, stackOffsetSilhouette } from 'd3-shape'
import { range } from 'd3-array'
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'

class StreamGraph extends Component {
  render() {

    const stackData = range(30).map(() => ({}))                          

    for (let x = 0; x<30; x++) {
      this.props.data.forEach(country => {
        stackData[x][country.id] = country.data[x]                       
      })
    }

    const xScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 30])
      .range([0, this.props.size[0]])

    const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 60])
      .range([this.props.size[1], 0])

    const stackLayout = stack()
      .offset(stackOffsetSilhouette)
      .order(stackOrderInsideOut)
      .keys(Object.keys(stackData[0]))                                   

    const stackArea = area()
      .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
      .y0(d => yScale(d[0]))
      .y1(d => yScale(d[1]))
      .curve(curveBasis)

    const stacks = stackLayout(stackData).map((d, i) => <path
        key={"stack" + i}
        d={stackArea(d)}
        style={{ fill: this.props.colorScale(this.props.data[i].launchday),
            stroke: "black", strokeOpacity: 0.25 }}
    />)

    return <svg width={this.props.size[0]} height={this.props.size[1]}>
      <g transform={"translate(0," + (-this.props.size[1] / 2) + ")"}>   
      {stacks}
      </g>
    </svg>
  }
}

export default StreamGraph
```

**Referencing StreamGraph.js in App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import StreamGraph from './StreamGraph'

class App extends Component {
   render() {
   return (
      <div className='App'>
      <div className='App-header'>
      <h2> D3 Dashboard</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
      <StreamGraph colorScale={colorScale} data={appdata} size={[1000,250]} />
      </div>
      </div>
   )
   }
}

export default App
```

**OR**

There is a javascript library **[React-D3](http://www.reactd3.org/)** which you can use in your application. React D3 Library [Examples](https://github.com/react-d3-library/react-d3-library-examples/blob/master/static/streamgraph.csv)

Comment: Is there a comprehensive list of these modules & their exports somewhere? It always takes me a long time to 1) Know what all the modules are 2) Know which module the functionality I need belongs to.

Comment: In case it affects anyone else - it looks like there are misformatted characters in the Barchart.js example that break the code if you copy-paste. There's a ’ in the d3-scale import that should become a single-quote and the minus symbol (-) describing the y value is actually an em-dash. Fixing those two characters fixed the example for me